# How do I remove the quote from the following regexp on ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/["]*(?<name>.*)[\"]*?\s*[<(](?<email>\w.*)[>)]/.match("\"The Boss\" <daboss@aol.com>")
```

and get the following result:

```
name = The Boss"
email = daboss@aol.com
```

How do I get rid of the last quote on The Boss"???

Feel free to refactor my regex to make it more sensical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `(?<name>)` is `.*`, which will eat anything, including double quotes. An easy way to fix that would be to change it to `.*?`. (That's a reluctant matcher; it matches as few characters as possible, rather than as many as possible.)

Another way to do it would be to use `[^"]*` rather than `.*`.

There is an important lesson to be learned about regexps here: whenever you write a regexp, don't just think about what you want to match; think about what you *don't* want to match. A *very* common source of errors with regexps is matching *too much*.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to disallow quotation marks in the name. This will fix your example:

```
/["]*(?<name>[^"]*)[\"]*?\s*[<(](?<email>\w.*)[>)]/.match("\"The Boss\" <daboss@aol.com>")
```

If you want to support backslash escaping, you'll need something more sophisticated, though.